# G++ Compiler Stalls [CodeBlocks]

Tags: linux, kali-linux, g++, code-blocks, stall

I am using CodeBlocks under Kali Linux and the g++ compiler stalls.

SOMETIMES, I hit compile and at the bottom I get the message: `g++ -fexceptions ...etc build main.o` ... and NOTHING happens. If I hit cancel I get the message: `Aborting build \n Process aborted`. But NOTHING happens.

The Compile/Run/Compile&Run buttons are still grayed out, and all I can do is restart CodeBlocks.

Sometimes compilation works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes I restart, change something meaningless and it works. Meaningless means replace some `short` with `short int` and adding some comments. It does not give any build errors, just stalls. Of course, when I do make mistakes I get build errors, so the issue is not from me writing wrong code.